# Returning file from ASP.NET MVC Action method - This request has been blocked because sensitive information

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying fetch the PDF file which is return in form of bytes from the API

**jQuery:**

```
// jQuery ajax to get fileId and token

window.location.href = "/APIFileDownload/GetFile?fileId= "+ response.fileId + "&token="+ response.token;
```

**C# (ASP.NET MVC)**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetFile(string fileId, string token)
{
    // call API with token and file Id
    // get bytes from string reponse
    
    bytes[] fileDownload = Convert.FromBase64String(apiResult.filecontent)
    return File(fileDownload, "application/pdf", "test_download.pdf")
}
```

**Error**:

> This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be
> disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request.
> To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

**Please let me know how to return the file from this method.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To allow GET requests, set JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206512/to-allow-get-requests-set-jsonrequestbehavior-to-allowget)

Comment: Are you sure that's *all* your code?  You don't have any other code that, maybe, provides a json result if there's an error?  eg as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562046/download-file-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Yes, this is fine. But my return type is File and not Json(). I cannot put AllowGet in return type File.

Comment: Change your action signature to `public FileResult GetFile(string fileId...` and see where it doesn't compile...